# Timer - show 0 to derised value in 2 second using jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have one value ,  for example : 50, i want to show countdown 0 to 50 in just 2 second,

how could i do that?

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" value="50"/>
<lable id="lbl"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztaenco3/1/

**i want value count down 0 to 50 ( ideally 50 can be any number,) and degree 0 to 360 ! in just 2 second**

** sorry for edit the question**

latests result = http://jsfiddle.net/vstq9t5L/1/ -

- in this result 3 problem - 
  [1] - it should be only one function
  [2] count 10000 is not finishing in 2 second, 
  [3] when count finish to 10000, then same time 360 should finish, not early or late

Comment: Is "degree" `label` text ? Is "value" `input` `value` ("0 to 50") ? Where is "degree 0 to 360" displayed ? Thanks

Comment: i updated my question including lastest efforts

Comment: Only `input`'s display count ? , not `label` element ?

Comment: ignore the html elements, i want display the numbers

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var myFirstVal = $("#Text1").val();
var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
    var mynewVal = parseInt($("#Text1").val()) + 1;
    $("#Text1").val(mynewVal);
    if (mynewVal >= 50) clearInterval(myInterval);
}, (2000 / 50));
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/ztaenco3/12/

Comment: it should start from 0 to 50 :) and stop at 50

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<p id="number">x</p>
<p id="number2">x</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
var paragraph = document.getElementById("number") 
var paragraph2 = document.getElementById("number2") 

function animateNumbers(countUpNumber, countDownNumber,time){

    var time = time * 100
    var x = 0;

    var gapUp = countUpNumber / time
    gapUp = Math.round( gapUp * 100 ) / 100

    var gapDown = countDownNumber / time
    gapDown = Math.round( gapDown * 100 ) / 100

    var animate = setInterval(function(){

        x += gapUp;
        var xRound = Math.floor(x);
        if (xRound > countUpNumber) xRound = countUpNumber;
        paragraph.innerHTML = xRound;

        countDownNumber -= gapDown;
        var yRound = Math.floor(countDownNumber);
        if (yRound < 0) yRound = 0;
        paragraph2.innerHTML = yRound;

        if ((x >= countUpNumber) && (countDownNumber <= 0)) clearInterval(animate);  

    }, 10)

}

animateNumbers(5000,360,2) // number to count up, number to count down, time in seconds
```

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/qvb5fnv9/

Comment: Hi Thanks, will you able to make count down to 0 to 360 degree based on 0 to 50, ie. when my number reached to 50 , degree also should reached to 360.

Comment: You welcome! Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ztaenco3/14/ ??

Comment: no, i want value count down 0 to 50 ( ideally 50 can be any number,) and degree 0 to 360 ! in just 2 second

Comment: i want both number finished at same time :( , i.e when 0 to 50 finished, the same time, 0 to 360 finish , and when i take large number, it doesnt work ! - http://jsfiddle.net/vstq9t5L/1/